# In C++ abs( *a - *b) does not return absolute value of negative number

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>

void update(int *a,int *b) {
    // Complete this function 
    (*a) = abs(*a + *b);
    (*b) = abs(*a - *b);   
}

int main() {
    int a, b;
    int *pa = &a, *pb = &b;

    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    update(pa, pb);
    printf("%d\n%d", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

I have the following code (from HackerRank C++ problems). If I have 4 and 5 as input it will return 9 and 4 as output rather than 9 and 1. I thought it will go 4 - 5 = abs(-1) = 1. Why does it not work like that?

Comment: When this line `(*b) = abs(*a - *b);` runs, what is the value of `*a`?

Comment: Why do you need to use pointers? Looks like an overkill to me.

Comment: You should start to use a debugger, you will then immediately see the answer to Blaze's question and understand your problem.

Comment: You're making the mistake that newbies sometimes make, that a program is a bunch of equations that describe a problem to be solved. However in most languages a program is really a series of instructions that are executed in a given order to solve a problem. So in your case the error is that you didn't realise that executing the first 'equation' changed the meaning of the second.

Answer (score 3):

You reassigned `*a` on the first line, and it's using that new value on the second line. You'll need a temporary to avoid that, e.g.:

```
int origa = *a;
*a = abs(origa + *b);
*b = abs(origa - *b);
```

Alternatively, you can get fancy with `tuple`s:

```
std::tie(*a, *b) = std::make_tuple(abs(*a + *b), abs(*a - *b));
```

which just computes and packs up the values first, then unpacks them after all the reads are done.

Comment: Origa... Sounds like the next challenger for Gojira's crown.

Answer (score 1):

```
 `void update(int *a,int *b) {
    // Complete this function
    *a=*a+*b;
    *b=abs(*a-(2**b));
}`
```

(2**b) is used because in the previous step we have changed the value of *a to *a+*b.
so we are subtracting 2 times.

*b = abs (*a - (2 * (*b));

*b = abs (9 - (2 * (5));

*b = abs (9 - (10));

*b = abs (-1);

*b = 1;

Answer (score 0):

Rather Use this Code As it is Simple. If the value of b is negative after subtracting. We just multiply by -1.

```
int origa = *a;
*a = origa + *b;
*b = origa - *b;
if (*b <0)
{
    *b=-1*(*b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"a" gets new value after executing `(*a) = abs(*a + *b);` , so now "b" gets the latest value of "a" , that's why it gives 4 instead of 1 (a=4+5=9,b = 9-5=4). So declare a temporary variable to use it for both a and b like this.

```
int temp=*a;
*a = temp+*b;
*b = abs(temp-*b);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it without using temporary variable, you can do like this:

```
void update(int *a, int *b) {
    // Complete this function 
    (*a) = abs(*a + *b);
    (*b) = abs(*a - *b -*b);
  }
```

Comment: This is not equivalent due to different overflow cases, and really a bad idea just from a standpoint of clarity, even if not for that.